# Print elements of arrays of same index in blocks

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, indexing, block

Having an array of arrays like below.

```
x = [ ["a","b","c","2"], ["d","e","f",""], ["g","h","i","j"] ]
```

I'm trying to print the Nth element of each array grouped by blocks like below:

```
Begin
- Value a -
- Value d -
- Value g -
End
Begin
- Value b -
- Value e -
- Value h -
End
Begin
- Value c -
- Value f -
- Value i -
End
Begin
- Value 2 -
- Value   -
- Value j -
End
```

The code below is what I've tried but without success. I'm getting "can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)"

```
x = [ ["a","b","c","2"], ["d","e","f",""], ["g","h","i","j"] ]

for j in 0.. x.map(&:size).max
    p "Begin"
    for i in 0..x.size      
        p x["#{i}"]["#{j}"]         
    end 
    p "End"
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help

#

Steve,

If the arrays inside have different size and I try to concatenate a string to the value like below, for the nil values I get error "can't convert nil to string". How can be taken nil as blanck value to avoid that error?

For example, having the array below

```
x = [ ["a","b"], ["d","e","f"] ]
```

get the output

```
Begin
- Value a -
- Value d -
End
Begin
- Value b -
- Value e -
End
Begin
- Value  -
- Value f -
End
```

The code I have so far is, ut I get error for 3rd iteration since first array is smaller than 2nd one:

```
x = [ ["a","b"], ["d","e","f"] ]
```

(0...(x.map(&:size).max)).each do |c|
     puts "Begin"
     x.each { |array| p "- Value " + array[c] + "-" }
     puts "End"
   end

Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing `p x[i][j]`

Also you want to use three dots in the range since array elements are numbered from 0 to (array.size - 1). Two dots will give you a range that includes the ending value, three dots gives you a range up to but not including the ending value.

A possibly simpler way...

```
(0...(x.map(&:size).max)).each do |c|
  puts "Begin"
  x.each { |array| p array[c] }
  puts "End"
end
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Steve for your help and answer. It works so fine. I don't completely understand why "x.each { |array| p array[0] }" prints the first element of each array, but "p x[0]" prints the first array of the arrays. I was confused initially about that :)

Comment: `x.each {|array| ` will execute the block for each sub-array within the outer array.  The variable `array` refers to the sub-array in the current iteration. So x.each will execute three times, the first time "array" will be the first array, the second time the second, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Steve. I understand more clearly now!

Comment: Hello again Steve, I've updated my original question. May you check below the "#" my new issue please. I have a problem with nil values. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. I was able to do it doing this "x.each { |array| p (array[c]==nil)?"value -":"value " + array[c].to_s + " -" }". Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
x.transpose.each do |group|
  puts "Begin"
  puts group.map {|el| "- Value #{el} -"}
  puts "End"
end
```

Comment: `transpose` leaps out here.

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for share another solution. In your case how would be to fix when arrays don't have same size?